# DataFrame.plot multiple lines in a figure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question with DataFram.plot(). I want a line graph in which the Years are in xlabel and Shipments are in ylabel, but the series are the Quarters column in the same graph. Please help me I'm new.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_ship = pd.read_csv('dmba/ApplianceShipments.csv') #importing the csv for the exercise

#Spliting the quarters and the years into two different columns

df_ship[['Quarter','Year']]= df_ship.Quarter.str.split('-',expand=True)
#Grouping the dataframe by Quarter
df_filt = df_ship.groupby(by=['Quarter'],axis=0)
#Creating the plot figure
fig1 = df_filt.plot(x='Year',y='Shipments')
```

As output I have 4 different line graphs

Comment: Could  you please provide a small reproducible example of your data instead of pd.read_csv('dmba/ApplianceShipments.csv')?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have an extract of your dataset but does the code below do what you want?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='Year',y='Shipments', hue='Quarter', data=df_ship)
```

From Seaborn [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html):

> hue : vector or key in data 
> Grouping variable that will produce lines with different colors. Can be either or numeric, although color mapping will behave
> differently in latter case.